# Jira - Can I lock an epic to prevent new tasks being linked to it?

Tags: jira

I have an epic in Jira which is used to group general bugs and tasks for the coming work period, but it is turning into a bit of a dumping ground for all and sundry.

Whilst I can obviously notify people to ask them not to keep doing this, I was wondering if there is a way to effectively "lock" an epic in Jira so that people cannot link bugs or tasks to that epic once it is locked?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Can you provide a use case? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand.  The epic is current so not closed.  The content should remain fixed to it's planned for content for the current dev period but, because it is an epic used to collate general tasks/bug found across our tools internally, people  have a tendency to raise an internal task and just link it to this current epic.  As I say, I can inform people to stop doing this but I was just wondering if I could also effectively lock the epic so we don't get any more tasks added to it.